# MySQL SELECT statement that groups results by id?

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-concat

I am trying to create a MySQL SELECT statement that will select a bunch of rows from a table and will group the results by the id of the row (multiple rows will have the same id).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have the following table:

```
id     |     name  
1      |     Art  
1      |     Arnold  
1      |     Anatoly  
2      |     Beatrice  
2      |     Bertha  
2      |     Betty  
3      |     Constantine  
3      |     Cramer
```

I'd like to have MySQL return the data grouped by id like so:

```
[1] => Art, Arnold, Anatoly
[2] => Beatrice, Bertha, Betty
[3] => Constantine, Cramer
```

I know I could do a simple SQL select, then loop over the result in PHP, but I'd like to let MySQL handle the grouping if possible.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM
  foo
GROUP BY
  id
```

But keep in mind:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)  system variable, which has a default value of 1024.

Comment: @MikeB, it haunts me everyday: I was born on 10/24. :P

Comment: thanks for the reply @VolkerK, but I will definitely run into the max length issue since I'm dealing with thousands of rows =)

Comment: @user why do you need such amount of data? what you gonna do with a line containing thousand of comma-separated names?

Comment: @user259878: the variable can be changed in the current session by `SET @@group_concat_max_len:= 1024*100;`, up to 4294967295. But the question of Col. Shrapnel is still relevant.